# Sepia Filter of CS50 pset4

Tags: c, cs50

So I've tried writing code for sepia filter, but its not working properly for corner cases. I dont find any issue. But error is being prompted.

The below image is the picture of my errors

I tried running the program in VS code, it gives desired output. But check50 prompts error message.

```
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            float r = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            float g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            float b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(0.393*r + 0.769*g + 0.189*b);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(0.349*r + 0.686*g + 0.168*b);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(0.272*r + 0.534*g + 0.131*b);

            if (image[i][j].rgbtRed > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
            }

            if (image[i][j].rgbtGreen > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = 255;
            }

            if (image[i][j].rgbtBlue > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
            }

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `sepia` function is almost correct. You just missed that with

```
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(0.393*r + 0.769*g + 0.189*b);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(0.349*r + 0.686*g + 0.168*b);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(0.272*r + 0.534*g + 0.131*b);
```

the members `rgbtRed`, `rgbtGreen` and `rgbtBlue` are only 8 bits and the behavior of assigning floating type values from 256 on to them is undefined; the following code to cap the values can't work. So cap the RGB values before assigning them:

```
            image[i][j].rgbtRed   = fmin(round(0.393*r + 0.769*g + 0.189*b), 255);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = fmin(round(0.349*r + 0.686*g + 0.168*b), 255);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue  = fmin(round(0.272*r + 0.534*g + 0.131*b), 255);
```

Comment: [std::clamp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp).

Comment: I see no indication that [CS50x](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/) includes the C++ language.

Comment: There's a [tag:C++] tag.

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me in CS50

```
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {

        int sepiaShadeR = round(0.393*image[i][j].rgbtRed + 0.769*image[i] 
[j].rgbtGreen + 0.189*image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
        int sepiaShadeG = round(0.349*image[i][j].rgbtRed + 0.686*image[i] 
[j].rgbtGreen + 0.168*image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
        int sepiaShadeB = round(0.272*image[i][j].rgbtRed + 0.534*image[i] 
[j].rgbtGreen + 0.131*image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
        if (sepiaShadeR > 255)
        {
            sepiaShadeR = 255;
        }
        if (sepiaShadeG > 255)
        {
            sepiaShadeG = 255;
        }
        if (sepiaShadeB > 255)
        {
            sepiaShadeB = 255;
        }
        image[i][j].rgbtRed = sepiaShadeR;
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sepiaShadeG;
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = sepiaShadeB;
    }
}
return;
}
```

Comment: I think signing float was the problem for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).